# fopen PHP error (expects parameter 1 to be resource)

Tags: php, fopen, fclose

I am trying to create a directory with a PHP file in it (that part works).

Now I am trying to open that PHP file and put in data, but I get error:

> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\wamp\www\dev 3\1\index2.php on line 13

and

> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\wamp\www\dev 3\1\index2.php on line 14

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$directory = substr(md5(rand(1000,10000)),2,8);
mkdir($directory);
$dir = './'.$directory.'/index.php';
$upload = fopen($dir,'x');
$data = '
data data data

';
fopen($dir, "w");
fwrite($dir, $data);
fclose($dir);
?>
```

Comment: With all due respect, next time it would be a good idea to look at the PHP docs for the function(s) you are having problems with **before** making a question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You need a resource handle and not string, as your error gracefully said :)

Use `$upload` instead of `$dir`:

```
<?php
$directory = substr(md5(rand(1000,10000)),2,8);
mkdir($directory);
$dir = './'.$directory.'/index.php';
$upload = fopen($dir,'x');
$data = '
data data data

';
/*fopen($dir, "w");
fwrite($dir, $data);
fclose($dir);
*/
fopen($upload, "w");
fwrite($upload, $data);
fclose($upload);
?>
```